# How to see if an array is contained (in the same order) of another array in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, contains

I have an array A of 1s and 0s and want to see if the larger array of bits B contains those bits in that exact order?
Example: A= [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1]

B= [0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1]
would be true as A is contained in B

Most solutions I have found only determine if a value IS contained in another matrix, this is no good here as it is already certain that both matrices will be 1s and 0s 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One (albeit unusual) option, since you're dealing with integer values, is to convert `A` and `B` to character arrays and use the [`contains`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contains.html) function:

```
isWithin = contains(char(B), char(A));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some obtuse vectorized ways to to do this, but by far the easiest, and likely just as efficient, is to use a loop with a sliding window,

```
A = [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1];
B = [0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1];
vec = 0:(numel(A)-1);
for idx = 1:(numel(B)-numel(A)-1)
   if all(A==B(idx+vec))
      fprintf('A is contained in B\n');
      break; % exit the loop as soon as 1 match is found
   end
end
```

Or if you want to know the location(s) in B (of potentially multiple matches) then,

```
A = [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1];
B = [0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1];
C = false(1,numel(B)-numel(A)-1);
vec = 0:(numel(A)-1);
for idx = 1:numel(C)
   C(idx) = all(A==B(idx+vec));
end
if any(C)
   fprintf('A is contained in B\n');
end
```

In this case

```
>> C
C =
  1×6 logical array
   0   0   0   1   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) between two signals for this, as a measure of local similarity.

For achieving good results, you need to shift A and B so that you don't have the value 0 any more. Then compute the correlation between the two of them with `conv` (keeping in mind that the convolution is the cross-correlation with one signal flipped), and normalize with the energy of A so that you get a perfect match whenever you get the value 1:

```
conv(B-0.5, flip(A)-0.5, 'valid')/sum((A-0.5).^2)
```

In the normalization term, flipping is removed as it does not change the value.

It gives:

```
[0 -0.5 0.25 1 0 0 -0.25 0]
```

4th element is 1, so starting from index equal to 4 you get a perfect match.